# How to use info from rest api response C#

Tags: c#, httprequest, jsonparser

I am trying to validate an API response but I can't seem to understand how to use the content of the response.

This is my response :

```
"{\"On\": false, \"value\": null,}"
```

And I would like to test for the value of "On" (if its true then... or false then...).

Here is my code so far :

```
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;

namespace APITest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            PostRequest("My API");

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        async static void PostRequest(string url)
        {
            IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> queries = new 
List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>()
            {
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Test","1")
            };
            HttpContent q = new FormUrlEncodedContent(queries);
            using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            {
                using (HttpResponseMessage response = await 
client.PostAsync(url,q))
                {
                    using (HttpContent content = response.Content)
                    {
                        string mycontent = await 
content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                        HttpContentHeaders headers = content.Headers;
                        Console.WriteLine(mycontent);

                    }          

                }

            }
        }
    }  
}
```

Comment: You're looking for a JSON parser.

Answer (score 1):

You create a class which represents that JSON structure and use a JSON serializor to de-serialize your string representation to an object of that class and use it as needed

Here i show you do it with JSON.NET

```
string mycontent = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
var result= Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ApiResult>(mycontent);
if (result!= null)
{
     if (result.On)
     {
        //do something, may be read, result.Value
     }
     else
     {
         //do something else
     }                 
}
```

Assuming you have a class like this

```
public class ApiResult
{
    public bool On { set; get; }
    public string Value { set; get; }
}
```

Comment: Hi Shju ,

Thanks for the advice. I seem to get an exception when trying to deserilaize with your solution.

Unhandled Exception: Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Error converting value "{"On": false, "value": null \n()"}" to type 'APITest.Program+ApiResult'. Path '', line 1, position 140. ---> System.ArgumentException: Could not cast or convert from System.String to APITest.Program+ApiResult.

Comment: myContent looks like escaping twice.

mycontent = "\"{\\\"On\\\": false, \\\"value\\\": null \\\\n()\\\"}\"\n"

Comment: Your json string does not look good. Are you manually generating it  ? It should be something like `string mycontent = "{\"On\":false,\"Value\":null}";`

Comment: Sorry i copied it quickly :) the json response looks like what you have noted.

And yes im altering a bit the json (just the names as for security reasons)